# Interpolate from curve data

Tags: matlab, polynomial, interpolation

I have these curves, 
[image: Life curves]

From this curve I can determine the life of a prop shaft due to gyroscopic forces at different yaw angles and certain speeds. I performed curve fitting on data points to get accurate high order polynomials for this interval of yaw angles. The polynomials are as follows,
y_150 = @(x) 22*((x-23)/4.9)^4 - 48*((x-23)/4.9)^3 + 27*((x-23)/4.9)^2 - 37*((x-23)/4.9) + 40;

y_200 = @(x) 11*((x-19)/4.8)^4 - 48*((x-19)/4.8)^3 + 73*((x-19)/4.8)^2 - 72*((x-19)/4.8) + 48;

y_212 = @(x) 23*((x-19)/4.8)^4 - 43*((x-19)/4.8)^3 + 22*((x-19)/4.8)^2 - 40*((x-19)/4.8) + 41;

But what about at 180 knots? Or 205 knots? Can I do some sort of 3 dimensional interpolation to account for different speeds? Since it is not considered good enough to use the closest speed value.

I would appreciate ANY ideas or comments on this problem.